# Perceptron: Do loop not returning a value

Tags: programming

I am trying to write a function that finds a simple best fit line for some data (Perceptron algorithm). Sadly it returns no output at all. Here's the code below:

```
x = {{3, .2, 1}, {1, .3, 1}, {4, .5, 1}, {2, .7, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1.2, 1}, {1, 1.7, 1}, {6, .2, 1}, {7, .3, 1}, {6, .7, 1}, {3, 1.1, 1}, {2, 1.5, 1}, {4, 1.7, 1}, {2, 1.9, 1}}
y = {{-1}, {-1}, {-1}, {-1}, {-1}, {-1}, {-1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}}
n = Length[y]
eta = .1

percep[w_] := 
    Do[If[(x[[i]].w) y[[i]] >= 0, , w += (eta y[[i]][[1]]) x[[i]]; Return[w]], {i, Range[n]}]

percep[{{.1},{.1},{.1}}]
```

What's meant to happen is that the function goes through every item in the list `X` multiplying it with `w` (which starts at `{{.1}, {.1}, {.1}}`) and then multiplying the result by `y` to see if the result is the correct sign or not. In the event the answer is 'not', it's supposed to stop the list and return a corrected `w`, which is fed back into the function for another attempt. Otherwise, the loop keeps going until the end.

I cannot get this function to return anything. Originally, for debugging purposes, I had an `Interrupt[]` in the part of the if that handles the `True` condition and that didn't even trigger.

What am I missing?

PS: This function is going to be fed into NestWhileList[], so it should just return w if w is altered.

Comment: Use `(Do[If[(x[[i]].w) y[[i]] >= 0, , w += (eta y[[i]][[1]]) x[[i]]], {i, Range[n]}]; w)`?

Comment: The nested lists in your argument to percep and in y seem wrong. Just print the value of the first argument to If to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: kguler: That sort of works, but I need the function to stop immediately if the If condition is false.

Comment: @kguler Use Break[] at the point where you have determined you want the immediate exit from the Do?

Comment: Try this, I *think* it's what you're after: percep[w_] := Module[{lc = 1},
  While[lc <= Length@y && First[(x[[lc]].w) y[[lc]]] >= 0, lc++];
  If[lc > Length@y, w, percep[w + (eta *y[[lc]][[1]]) x[[lc]]]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem— your comments all helped immensely.

```
(x[[i]].w) y[[i]]
```

yields a single-element list like `{0.1}`. Because of this, the if condition was defaulting to undefined. I changed it to

```
((x[[i]].w) y[[i]])[[1]]
```

and this fixed it.

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You can mark your answer as "accepted" by clicking the grey arrow under the vote icons on the left of the answer.